# How to make settings persist after uninstall on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to make a certain setting stay on the device even when the app itself has been uninstalled. For iOS we are using user's keychain to store this information. Is it possible on WP8 somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep, let's say user settings after an app is uninstalled, I highly doubt that this is possible on Windows Phone. First of all it would create a lot of orphan files on the phone that you would not be able to get rid of. One of the services on Windows Phone is `Package Manager`. This manager is in charge of installing/uninstalling apps, keeping track of what is pinned to the start screen and other metadata about an app and any extensibility points like `Share...`, etc. If you uninstall an app this manager should clean everything related to you app, even your user settings in any file or `IsolatedStorage` that you create.

iPhone and Android give you an ability to use some sort of file manager to explore your phone. As far as I can remember you could use `Putty` to connect to your phone to see the folders and stuff. In Windows Phone you cannot go this far. There are some tools like [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) that you can use to check the installed apps, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Apps and all their related data are stored in sandboxed folders. When an app is uninstalled this whole folder is deleted. As such this means that all saved data is removed.

There are two, probably non-ideal, workarounds.

1. You could create an image saved in the users photo library. You could embed the identifier in the image or it's name but the user has control of these images and may delete it. You also can't programmatically delete such files so you may end up with lots on the device. Having lots of "rogue" files on a device is also likely to cause a user to tidy them up (delete them).
2. You could store a record of the setting, linked to the device on a web server. This has the downside of needing to maintain the server and handling data sync and offline scenarios.